# Dice Game HTML 5 Template

Tags: silverlight, flash, html

Are there free templates for creating dice games using HTML5/JScripts (preferable), or Flash, or Silverlight?

Regards,

Comment: Do you mean templates for games, like a game-builder?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of dice game?

**HTML5**

There are some basic HTML5 examples here:
http://faculty.purchase.edu/jeanine.meyer/html5/html5explain.html

[This book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/html/9781430233831/dice-game/html5_comma_css_comma_and_javascript-004#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE0MzAyMzM4MzEvMjE=) looks like it has a more advanced HTML5 tutorial and it's possible to sign up for a free trial to access the contents.

**Silverlight**

There's some sample code for 3D dice in Silverlight on [this site](http://www.edwardsmale.co.uk/Dice).

Comment: @noober: I've added an example for Silverlight - you may be best being a bit more specific in your question about what you're actually trying to achieve.  Do you have examples that you've seen that you'd like to recreate?